# opengrock file path search now needs a quoted value

Tags: opengrok

We just upgraded from opengrok-0.11.1 to opengrok-1.0 to allow access to the history and annotations etc.

However many search strings now need quoted. We used to be able to search for a file path containing unquoted hosts.txt which now finds hundreds of matches vs a quoted search for "hosts.txt" which finds the expected two files. Is there some default we can tweek to change the analyzers being used for different fields. Is this a bug?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the OpenGrok help (***OpenGrok*** > ***Help***):

> if you want just exact path, enclose it in "", e.g. "src/mypath",
>   otherwise dividers will be removed and you get more hits

This change happened on 24-Oct-13 due to Lucene changes according to the [issue 672](https://github.com/OpenGrok/OpenGrok/issues/672) (where you can find more info about).

Comment: A step backwards in usefulness. I agree with the point in 672 where this was declared a stopper. It may well be for us. But thanks - anyhow.